# Can I have sub graph structures as xtics in GnuPlot?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I want to show sub graph structures as X-axis label. Is it possible to do something like this in Gnuplot?[image: Subgraphs as X-axis label]

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a set of functions that return the position of the points

```
px(M,n) = x0 + M * d + (n==0 ? 0 : n==1 ? a/2 : a)
py(M,n) = y0 + (n==0 ? 0 : n==1 ? a : 0)
```

set the points as objects

```
do for [M=1:13] {do for [n=1:3] {set object circle M*3+n at px(M,n),py(M,n)}}
```

and then set all the individual arrows

```
set arrow 11 from px(1,1),py(1,1) to px(1,2),py(1,2)
set arrow 12 from px(1,x), ...
```

perhaps an additional function set to take into account the diameter of the circles for each arrow

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the answer. I had a doubt about the functions returning the positions. I am confused about the variables used. How do I set the x0 and y0 values? The "d" parameter gives me the distance right? And what about "a"? Sorry for the naiveness but not understanding the positions on the graph.

Comment: "a" is the approximate size of each triangle. Check "help coordinates", you can also give the positions in absolute screen coordinates. The necessary values of x0,y0,a,d depend on your graph, you really should be able to find that out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge. As @Karl already wrote in his answer, you can draw circles and arrows in a loop. The positions of the circles is more or less obvious and can be generated by simple functions. However, for the type and direction of arrows I haven't found a simple function, hence I used a table to shorten the code for drawing the arrows.

A few things to mention:

- it will look differently depending on the terminal and the canvas size and ratio
- you have to fine tune the parameters `dx`, `dy`, `yshift`, `Radius`, and `myBottomMargin`.
- if you want to take into account the radius of the circles for not covering the arrow head tips (as @Karl mentioned), this will probably be not so simple (see [gnuplot: arrows between circles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65097645/7295599)), because x- and y-scale of the graph typically will *not* be the same. But as long as the circles and arrow heads are that small it probably doesn't matter too much.

**Code:** (works with gnuplot 5.0.0, the version at the time of OP's question)

```
### some graphics as xtic labels
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    set samples 13
    plot [1:13] '+' u 1:($1**2) w table
unset table

# settings for xtic triangle graphs
myBottomMargin = 0.2
dx = 0.35                   # triangle half-width (relative xtic distance)
dy = 0.08                   # triangle height (screen coordinates)
yshift = 0.08               # triangle y-offset (screen coordinates)
Radius = 0.07               # circle radius in x-dimensions
Px(M,n) = M + (n-1)*dx      # circle x position, M from 1 to 13, n from 0 to 2
Py(M,n) = ((M-1)%2 + n%2)%2 *dy + yshift   # circle y position, M from 1 to 13, n from 0 to 2

# -1=reverse arrow, 0=no arrow, 1=normal arrow, 2=two head arrow
#      M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9 M10 M11 M12 M13
A01 = "-1   1   1   2   2   1  -1  -1   2   1   1   2   2"  # arrow from point 0 to point 1
A12 = " 1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1   1   2"  # arrow from point 1 to point 2
A20 = " 0   0   0   0   0   0  -1  -1   1   2  -1   2   2"  # arrow from point 2 to point 0

set style arrow 1 backhead lt -1 filled fixed   # "reverse" arrow
set style arrow 2 nohead   lc 0xff000000        # no arrow (or transparent arrow)

set style arrow 3 head     lt -1 filled fixed   # "normal" arrow
set style arrow 4 heads    lt -1 filled fixed   # "two-head" arrow
myArrowStyle(M,n) = 2 + (n==0 ? int(word(A01,M)) : n==1 ? int(word(A12,M)) : int(word(A20,M)))

# draw the graphs
set style fill solid 1.0 border lc "black"
do for [M=1:13] {
    do for [n=0:2] {
        set arrow M*3+n from Px(M,n), screen Py(M,n) to Px(M,(n+1)%3), screen Py(M,(n+1)%3) as myArrowStyle(M,n)
        set object M*3+n circle at Px(M,n), screen Py(M,n) size Radius fc "grey" front
    }
}

set bmargin screen myBottomMargin
set xtics offset 0,-2.5 out  # -2.5 for gnuplot V5.0.0, for V5.2.8 use -1.5
set boxwidth 0.8
set grid xtics,ytics

set xrange [0:14]
plot $Data u ($0+1):2:xtic(sprintf("{/:Italic M%d}",$0+1)) w boxes notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:** (using gnuplot 5.0.0, with `set wxt term size 750,350`)

[image]